# How to correctly configure fonts for OpenJDK apps in nixpkgs?

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, x11, nixos, nixpkgs

When I run IntelliJ inside of Docker using a nixpkgs environment, I see a lot of missing characters in the GUI:
[image]

A possibly unrelated problem is that the act of selecting text (when selectable) seems to improve the situation - see the transition from the second to thirt image in the attached screenshots.

I have a relatively easy to reproduce [example](https://github.com/CornellCAC/docker-nix-intellij) (assuming one has docker available). I haven't tested this on NixOS directly, but may have to try that next to rule out issues: my current setup is based on that of [kurron/docker-intellij](https://github.com/kurron/docker-intellij), which does NOT have this problem (both mine and his are ultimately based on the same Ubuntu 16.04 docker image), leading me to believe it is a problem either in the OpenJDK in nixpkgs, or some bad interaction between nixpkgs X/fonts and the Ubuntu base system used.

To reproduce, you can ignore the README for now, just do:

```
source build.sh
./idea.sh # This will start the container
idea-ultimate # this should be run inside the container
```

***Note*** that `idea.sh` runs `xhost +` and performs some volume mounts, so please inspect before running if you are concerned.

Things that DO seem to work without font issues from the same container:

- `gedit` (no java involved: `nix-env -i gedit`)
- [JDiskReport](http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/jdiskreport/): (java involved - fonts work but don't look great, so probably a separate issue); download with `wget`, unzip with `unzip`, and run with `java -jar ...`

I assume IntelliJ is still based on Swing - but haven't seen any recent confirmation of this. If so, I could do more targeted testing.

Comment: This looks like it is probably an issue with the openjdk build in nixpkgs, see https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/29151